# Calling functions as if in own caller?

Tags: python, debugging

I'm trying to replicate an error-checking pattern that I often use when programming in C, in Python. I have a function `check` as follows:

```
def check(exceptions, msg, handler):
    def wrapped(func, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except exceptions as err:
            log_err(msg)
            # Do something with handler
    return wrapped
```

By calling `check` with appropriate arguments and then calling the result with a function and its arguments, it's possible to reduce a `try-except` statement to as little as two lines of code without really sacrificing clarity (in my opinion, anyway).

For example

```
def caller():
    try:
        files = listdir(directory)
    except OSError as err:
        log_err(msg)
        return []
    # Do something with files
```

becomes

```
def caller():
    c = check(OSError, msg, handler)
    files = c(listdir, directory) # caller may return [] here
    # Do something with files
```

The issue is that in order for this transformation to be transparent to the rest of the program it's necessary for `handler` to execute exactly as if it were written in the scope of the *caller* of `wrapped`. (`handler` need not be a function object. I'm after an effect, not a method.)

In C I would just use macros and expand everything inline (since that's where I would be writing the code anyway), but Python doesn't have macros. Is it possible to achieve this effect in some other way?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you intend to use this (i.e., what you need it to do)?

Comment: Sure. I'll add something more concrete.

Comment: In your example, what do you want `handler` to do?  Are you saying that if an error is raised, you want the function that called `c(...)` to return `[]`, or are you saying you want the expression `c(...)` to evaluate to `[]`?

Comment: The former. The caller of `c(...)` should return `[]`. Obviously this should only be used when the effects of `handler` are 'close at hand' so to speak.

Comment: *I'm trying to replicate an error-checking pattern that I often use when programming in C, in Python.* Bad idea! Writing python as if it was C leads to unmaintanible/non-idiomatic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to write Python code to create an object `c` so that, when you call `c`, the function that called it returns.  You can only return from a function by literally typing a `return` statement directly in that function's body (or falling off the end).

You could easily make it so that your "checked" function simply *returns* the default value.  The caller can then use it as normal, but it can't make the caller itself return.  You could also write a decorator for `caller` that catches your specified errors and returns `[]` instead, but this would catch all `OSError`s raised anywhere in `caller`, not just ones raised by calling a particular function (e.g., `listdir`).  For instance:

```
def check(exceptions, msg, handler):
    def deco(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except exceptions as err:
                print "Logged error:", msg
                return handler(err)
        return wrapped
    return deco

def handler(err):
    return []

@check(ZeroDivisionError, "divide by zero", handler)
def func(x):
    1/0

>>> func(1)
Logged error: divide by zero
[]
```

The situation you describe seems somewhat unusual.  In most cases where it would be worth it to factor out the handling into a "handler" function, that handler function either couldn't know what value it wants the caller to return, or it could know what to return just based on the error, without needing to know what particular line raised the error.

For instance, in your example, you apparently have a function `caller` that might raise an `OSError` at many different points.  If you only have one place where you need to catch `OSError` and return `[]`, just write one try/except and it's no big deal.  If you want to catch *any* `OSError` in the function and return `[]`, decorate it as shown above.  What you describe would seem to only be useful in cases where you want to catch more-than-one-but-not-all possible `OSError`s raised in `caller`, and yet in all those cases you want to return the same particular value, which seems rather unusual.

Comment: This isn't quite right, but I'll accept 'not possible' in lieu of another answer. I do indeed want to respond to some-but-not-all exceptions of a particular type. I find this problem occurs most often with `OSError` and `IOError`, possibly because they're so generic.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I don't quite understand, but can't you just put the handler inside the calling function?

```
def caller():
    def handler():
        print("Handler was called")
    # ...
```

### A better way...

Or, if you want to simplify the way you call it, you can use `with` statements to achieve the desired effect.  This will be a lot easier, I think, and it's a lot less of a "hack":

```
class LogOSError(object):
    def __init__(self, loc):
        self.loc = loc
    def __enter__(self):
        return None
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if isinstance(exc_value, OSError):
            print("{}: OSError: {}".format(self.loc, exc_value))
            return True
```

You can use it like this:

```
with LogOSError('example_func'):
    os.unlink('/does/not/exist')
```

And the output is:

```
>>> with LogOSError('some_location'):
...     os.unlink('/does/not/exist')
... 
some_location: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/does/not/exist'
```

Comment: I want `handler` to effect the behavior of `caller`. Not just for logging or returning values but to achieve a general effect. Just logging is comparatively easy. Using a `with` statement for logging is an interesting idea, although I'm not sure how to avoid effectively hiding the exception.

Comment: @yew: You don't have to hide the exception, that's what `return True` does.

Comment: Ah, so it does. I'll have to think about which of the `with` statement and `log_err` function reads better.